# Can you make a web app into a mobile app with meteor?

Tags: cordova, meteor, mobile, web-applications

I want to take an already made webapp in meteor and change it so that it works as a mobile app on an android device. Whenever I run the app on the browser it works fine but if I try to run it on my android device I just get a black screen. I also get `I20190708-09:41:59.751(-5)? W/MeteorWebApp( 9421):` when I try to run it as a mobile app. What call should I be using to get this to run properly?

Comment: I did pretty much exactly what you are asking. Please follow this guide, it's pretty good! https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html

Comment: @PatrickDaVader I tried to follow that guide and it caused more problems. Any other ideas?